# Cartesian product in RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java

Is it possible to get Cartesian product of two Observables in rxjava?

Something like this:

```
A -> 1,2,3
B -> a,b
A x B -> (1, a), (1, b), (2, a), (2, b), (3, a), (3, b)
```

Comment: So when c arrives in B then A x B produces "c multiplied with the elements arrived in A so far" ?

Comment: My gut feeling (based on the Reactive course) is that it is possible but this is just a feeling :) sorry , my RX is a little rusty.

Comment: The material for week 4 might have the answer https://www.coursera.org/course/reactive

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you want is to produce, for one number, as pair as you have letters.
So you can easily achive this using `map` and `flatMap` operator.

```
    Observable<Integer> number = Observable.from(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
    Observable<String> letters = Observable.from(Arrays.asList("a", "b"));

    Observable<Pair> cartesian = number.flatMap((n) -> letters.map((l) -> new Pair(n, l)));
```

Comment: Thanx David, I stumbled upon exactly this need ;) But this is the first version, I need a version which computes the cartesian product of variable size list of Observables. Trickier.

Comment: You can take this approach and continually add flatMap() in a for-loop.

Comment: fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    
    val sources = listOf(
        Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
        Observable.just(10, 20, 30, 40, 50),
        Observable.just(100, 200, 300, 400, 500)
    )
    var cartesianProduct: Observable<List<Int>>? = null
    for (obs in sources) {
        if (cartesianProduct == null) {
            cartesianProduct = obs.map { listOf(it) }
        } else {
            cartesianProduct = cartesianProduct.flatMap { list -> obs.map { list.plus(it) }}
        }
    }

    cartesianProduct!!.subscribe(::println)
}

Answer (score 1):

Is "join" not what you looking for?

```
    Observable<Integer> a = Observable.fromArray(1, 2, 3);
    Observable<String>  b = Observable.fromArray("a", "b");

    Observable<?> left  = Observable.never();
    Observable<?> right = Observable.never();

    Observable<Pair<Integer, String>> pairs = a.join(b, (aa)->left, (bb)->right, (ai, bi)-> Pair.of(ai, bi));
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is pseudo for Cartesian mapping.

```
A  ->  Pair<A,"letter">  ->  C
B  ->  Pair<B,"number">  ->  D

Merge(C,D) -> lift(new CartesianOperator) -> Result
```

The Cartesian operator would store a list of numbers, and a list of characters.

In the event that a unique character is introduced. You generate responses for every combination of the unique character with your list of recorded numbers. Then you add your unique character to the charter-list, then repeat the process.

You do the same for unique numbers.

In the end you'll be able to send Something like 1,1,2,3 and a,b,b, and receive something like (a,1)(a,2)(a,3)(b,1)(b,2)(b,3)

**Edit:**

So here is a quick, and admittedly un-scalable, implementation that would work. It takes a pair object.

Where Value 1 is your 'a', 'b', '1', '2', or '3', and 
Value 2 is your type'('number' or 'character')

It returns and observable pair of characters mapped to numbers.

```
public class CartesianOperator implements Observable.Operator<Pair<String,String>,Pair<String,String>> {


@Override
public Subscriber<? super Pair<String, String>> call(final Subscriber<? super     Pair<String, String>> subscriber) {
return new Subscriber<Pair<String, String>>() {
  List<String> numbers;
  List<String> characters;
  @Override
  public void onCompleted() {

  }

  @Override
  public void onError(Throwable e) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onNext(Pair<String, String> stringStringPair) {

    if(stringStringPair.second == "number")
    {
      if(numbers.size() == 0)
      {
        numbers.add(stringStringPair.first);
      }
      else
      {
        if(numbers.contains(stringStringPair.first))
        {}
        else
        {
          for(String temp: characters)
          {
            //Return Every permutation of existing characters with new number
            subscriber.onNext( new Pair<String,String>(temp,stringStringPair.first));
          }
        }

      }
    }
    else // Assume vallue is a character
    {
      if(characters.size() == 0)
      {
        characters.add(stringStringPair.first);
      }
      else
      {
        if(characters.contains(stringStringPair.first))
        {}
        else
        {
          for(String temp: numbers)
          {
            //Return Every permutation of existing numbers with new character
            subscriber.onNext( new Pair<String,String>(stringStringPair.first,temp));
          }
        }
      } 
    }
  }
};
}
}
```

If you have no idea what a pair object is, Its essentially an object that encapsulates two other objects.

```
pairObject.first
```

Returns the first object of my pair

```
pairObject.second
```

Returns the second object of my pair

I think its deprecated by now.