# Rx Java - combining each pair of two observables emitions

Tags: rx-java

Suppose

```
Observable<Integer> o1 = Observable.just(0, 1, 2);
Observable<Integer> o2 = Observable.just(2, 4, 6);
```

I need to build emition of numbers, which are each number from `o2` divided by each number from `o1`, but also avoid divide by zero.

I.e. I need some operator, producing

```
2 (2 / 1)
1 (2 / 2)
4 (4 / 1)
2 (4 / 2)
6 (6 / 1)
3 (6 / 1)
```

Any suggestions?

Guys, thanks for anwers, you are right!

But digging my real case deeper I had more difficult problem. Please give a look to [Rx java - difficult case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43834291/rx-java-difficult-case).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26588822/3903847 you can filter in the map division by zero

Answer (score 1):

Will this do (haven't checked in IDE, but should be working)?

```
Observable<Integer> o1 = Observable.just(0, 1, 2);
Observable<Integer> o2 = Observable.just(2, 4, 6);

Observable<Integer> o1nonZero = o1.filter(new Predicate<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public boolean test(Integer integer) throws Exception {
        return integer != null && integer != 0;
    }
})

o1nonZero.flatMap(new Function<Integer, Observable<Integer>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<Integer> apply(Integer integer2) throws Exception {
        return o1.map(new Function<Integer, Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer apply(Integer integer1) throws Exception {
                return integer2 / integer1;
            }
        })
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Observable<Integer> o1 = Observable.just(0, 1, 2);
Observable<Integer> o2 = Observable.just(2, 4, 6);
MathUtil.cartesianProduct(Observable.just(o2, o1))
    .filter(array -> array[1] != 0)
    .map(array -> array[0] / array[1])
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

But what is `cartesianProduct`?

See [Cartesian Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) for its definition and [n-ary cartesian product in rxjava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43164578/n-ary-cartesian-product-inrxjava) for its implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Hope this helps you too.

```
    Observable<Integer> num1 = Observable.just(0, 1, 2);
    Observable<Integer> num2 = Observable.just(2, 4, 6);

    num2.flatMap(
            i2 -> num1.filter(i -> i != 0)
                    .map(i1 -> i2 / i1)
    ).subscribe(
            s -> Log.v("", "result-> " + s),
            error -> error.printStackTrace()
    );
```