# Rx java - difficult case

Tags: rx-java

Suppose

`Observable<Integer> obs = Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);`

I need a sequence, where each **even** number of `obs` **multiplied by count of even** numbers in `obs`, and each **odd** number of `obs` **multiplied by count of odd** numbers in `obs`.

I.e. in given case there are 2 evens and 3 odds, so result sequence must be

```
3  (1 * 3)
4  (2 * 2)
9  (3 * 3)
8  (4 * 2)
15 (5 * 3)
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with splitting the `Observable` to odd and even streams, then iterate over each stream and multiply by the count of each split stream:

```
Observable<Integer> obs = Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
Observable<Integer> oddsObservable = obs.filter(integer -> integer % 2 == 1);
Observable<Integer> evenObservable = obs.filter(integer -> integer % 2 == 0);
Observable.merge(
       oddsObservable.flatMap(odd -> oddsObservable.count().map(count -> odd * count)),
       evenObservable.flatMap(even -> evenObservable.count().map(count -> even * count))
)
      .sorted()
      .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

if you're doing it over in-memory lists/arrays you might consider using `Java 8 Stream API`, and doing the same, the code is very similar:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
List<Integer> oddsList = list.stream().filter(integer -> integer % 2 == 1).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Integer> evenList = list.stream().filter(integer -> integer % 2 == 0).collect(Collectors.toList());

Stream.of(oddsList.stream().map(odd -> odd * (int) oddsList.stream().count()),
    evenList.stream().map(even -> even * (int) evenList.stream().count()))
    .flatMap(integerStream -> integerStream)
    .sorted()
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

in my machine it runs faster with order of magnitude (~ x12 ).

If the source of items/numbers id over time producer consider optimizing the Reactive approach to avoid resubscribe multiple times to `Observables` (replay/cache etc.)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
    Observable<Integer> obs = Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

    Observable<Integer> evenCount = obs.filter(integer -> integer % 2 == 0);
    Observable<Integer> oddCount = obs.filter(integer -> integer % 2 != 0);


    obs.flatMap(
            integer -> {
                if (integer % 2 == 0) {
                    return evenCount.count().map(count -> count * integer).toObservable();
                } else {
                    return oddCount.count().map(count -> count * integer).toObservable();
                }
            }
    ).subscribe(
            s -> Log.v("", "answer -> " + s),
            error -> error.printStackTrace()
    );
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Observable<Integer> obs = Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
List<Integer> count = obs.groupBy(i -> i % 2)
    .sorted((g1, g2) -> g1.getKey() - g2.getKey())
    .concatMap(go -> go.count())
    .toList()
    .toBlocking()
    .first();
obs.map(i -> i * count.get(i % 2))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Traverse twice.